# PyDev, Eclipse & Python 3 - disable __module_not_in_the_pythonpath__ completition

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

I'm using PyDev and Eclipse to manage upgrading from python 2 to python 3, and I'm running into a weird issue on one project. The code contains obvious fail points for python 3:

```
import httplib
import urllib2
```

However the interpreter doesnt mark these as `UndefinedImports` - in fact, there are no marked errors in the code at all! Instead, if I highlight over one of these Imports, the tooltip displays:

```
httplib: found at __module_not_in_the_pythonpath__
```

What does that mean? How can I disable this automatic search so that I only get what is actually in my interpreter's configured libs?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this means that your current file isn't in source folder in PyDev.

See: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for details on how to configure the source folder for your project.

If you aren't able to sort it out with that, please provide a screenshot showing the `PyDev package explorer` with the file expanded up to the file where you're trying to check to help in diagnosing the issue better.

Comment: that fixed it! interestingly in this case, the source folder was the root folder, so I didn't think it needed to be added. thank you for your help!